# Wcf library in Windows Service

Tags: sql-server, wcf, windows-services

I am unable to connect from my windows service to SQL server

> Exception:Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Login failed for user
>   'LOBAANSOFTWARES\LBS-PC-19$'. (Fault
>   Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail,
>   likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true,
>   whose value is:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Login failed for user
>   'LOBAANSOFTWARES\LBS-PC-19$'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection
>   owningObject) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnecti...

Is their is another service to  start for resolve this solution

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Same goes for error messages - please use the "blockquote" (") key for those!!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

> **Login failed** for user
>   'LOBAANSOFTWARES\LBS-PC-19$'.

That user (the machine name of the machine your service is running on) doesn't have any permissions to log on to SQL Server.

You can either:

- give that user rights to connect to SQL Server and the proper database(s)
- have the service run under a different user account which has the rights to SQL Server
- define a specific connection string in your NT service application to use a particular user to connect to SQL Server

Your connection string probably looks something like:

```
server=(your server name);database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

This attempts to connect to SQL server with the user that's running the service - by default your machine's computer account.

You can change your connection string to use a specific SQL Server user you've created instead:

```
server=(your server name);database=YourDatabase;User ID=YourNewUser;Pwd=Top$Secret
```

Comment: here i'm using wcf service to connect SQL server it is work fine with console application and web application but when i host this wcf service in windows service and then call the wcf function then i have got this problem and their is all the rights to my machine to connect SQL Server

Comment: actually i can't able to start my windows service here i connect to SQL server as Windows Authentication

Comment: @Vikram: yes, of course - if you run a console app, then it runs **as you** - under your user context. That user probably has permission to connect to SQL Server. Try to stop your service, change the account the service runs under to yourself, and try again - I'm convinced now your service **can** connect to SQL Server since it's running under **your** user context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the security on your database to make sure the user exists and has sufficient authority to connect?  Is the Windows service using the correct password for the user account it runs as?